# Users' images aren't showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've been wrestling with this for a while and the users' images (or the default) in my index page aren't displaying. I'm using paperclip and it works everywhere else but this page.

user.rb

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { larger: "280x280#", medium: "300x300#", thumb: "50x50#", followp: "208x208#" }, 
                            default_url: "/assets/default.png",
                            :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

user_controller.rb

```
def index
  #@user = User.find(params[:id]) **This causes the error "couldn't find the user w/o an id"**
  @users = User.where.not("id = ?",current_user.id).order("created_at DESC")
  @conversations = Conversation.involving(current_user).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="content-box">
  <h1>Chat</h1>
    <div>
  <% if @conversations.any? %>
    <ul class="media-list">
      <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
        <li class="media">
          <%= image_tag @user.avatar(:thumb), class: "media-object pull-left" unless @user.nil? **removing this causes "undefined method avatar for nil:NilClass"** %>
```

conversation_controller.rb

```
def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).first
  else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end

  render json: { conversation_id: @conversation.id }
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
  @reciever = interlocutor(@conversation)
  @messages = @conversation.messages
  @message = Message.new
end
```

**Update**

conversation model

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("conversations.sender_id =? OR conversations.recipient_id =?",user.id,user.id)
  end

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :conversations, :foreign_key => :sender_id
```

Comment: `@user` variable is not set in index action.

Comment: When I add `@user = User.find(params[:id])` I get the error _Couldn't find User without an ID_

Comment: how are you how are you authorizing users in your app? any gem used?

Comment: I use bcrypt, but thats it

Comment: @user3693398 Is there any relationship between conversations and users please post your model code also.

Comment: @anusha you got it .. :)

Comment: @user3693398 Try to write `<%= image_tag conversation.user.avatar(:thumb), class: "media-object pull-left" unless conversation.user.nil?%>` please let me know if not works

Comment: I get _undefined method `user' for #<Conversation:0xadacf60>_

Comment: @user3693398 please add your @conversations value what you get in `index` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was actually hidden in a helper method

```
<%= image_tag conversation_interlocutor(conversation).avatar(:thumb), class: "media-object pull-left" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="content-box">
  <h1>Chat</h1>
    <div>
  <% if @conversations.any? %>
    <ul class="media-list">
      <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
        <li class="media">
          <%= image_tag User.find_by_id(conversation.sender_id).avatar(:thumb), class: "media-object pull-left" %>
```

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help.